# Code platoon conditional statements problem set

Tags: javascript

Getting my coding learning path started and I've run across a hiccup. I'm trying to write a program that represents the below;

```
// Write a program that prints a message to the screen based on a users age and country.

// Feel free to change these variables or create new ones so you can test all cases.

const age = 20

const country = 'USA'

// if the user is younger than 16 print "You're not old enough to do anything yet."

// if the user is at least 16 but not yet 18 print "Be careful driving."

// if the user is 18 but not yet 21 and the user lives in the USA pring "Go Vote!"

// if the user is at least 18 but younger than 21 and lives outside of the US print "You can probably have some wine."

// In all other cases print "You're old enough to figure it out for yourself."
```

**So far ive got this:**

```
const age = 20

const country = "USA"

const otherCountry = "Other country"

console.log(age)

console.log(otherCountry)


if (age < 16 ) {
  console.log("You're not old enough to do anything.") 
  }
  else if (age >=16 && age <=18) {
    console.log ("Be careful driving")
    }
    else if (age >=18 && age <=21 && country) {
      console.log("Go Vote!")
    }
    else if (age >=18 && age <=21 && otherCountry){
      console.log ("You can prbably have some wine")
    }
    else
    {console.log ("You're old enough to figure it out")
    }
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get the country to be expressed in the "else if" statement. Noobies got to start somewhere. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looking at your code, if you are simply trying to console.log information, it doesn't work because `country` or `otherCountry` would have to be a boolean (True or False), since that's essentially what you're testing. I would recommend not setting a `CONST` for `otherCountry`. What you want do is check the value so `country == 'usa'` or `country == 'other'` then use those in your `else ifs` instead.

Comment: You have a boolean expression (`a && b && c`), which means that a, b and c are all cast to boolean values first if required. a and b are already booleans because `a >= b` is either true or false. c however is `"country"`, which is what's called "truthy". It always ends up being evaluated as true, regardless of the contents. Any non-empty string is.

Comment: Also note that the existence of `otherCountry` is pointless here. You want to check whether the user's country is "USA" or not, so all you need is `country == "USA"`, which will again either be true or false.

Comment: Here's one way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/xvyr7s4k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your logic.

First of all *not yet 18* probably means `< 18` and not `<= 18`. (same for 21)

Second, once you are in your `"Go vote"` branch, you can never enter the `"Wine"` branch anymore, because once, one condition is hit in an `if .. else if .. else` no other conditions will be evaluated any more.

So, if you have a person between 18 and 21, you have to check the addtional condition (ie lives in USA or any other country) in that branch.

```
let age = 19;
let livesin = "USA";

if (age < 16 ) {
  console.log("You're not old enough to do anything.") 
}
//you don't need >=16 here, because as the first condition failed
//we alread know that age >= 16
else if (age < 18) {  
  console.log ("Be careful driving")
}
//you don't need >=18 here, because as the first and second condition failed
//we already know that age >= 18
else if (age <21) {
  //for people between 18 and 21, check if they live in the USA or not
  if (livesin === "USA") console.log("go vote");
  else console.log("You can prbably have some wine")
}
else {
  console.log ("You're old enough to figure it out")
}
```

Comment: @zipzit If you show some effort and only have minor issues, maybe ...

Comment: @zipzit Not sure that's fair. The OP did make an effort to implement quite a bit of it. The homework questions which deserve ignoring are the ones which just list the requirements and show absolutely zero effort, just wanting a free ride. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)
 if you haven't already.

Comment: @derpirscher the only thing I'd say (I haven't tested if your code actually works, let's assume it does for now) is that you haven't really helped the OP understand why something like `else if (age >=18 && age <=21 && country)` didn't work, which was their specific question. They apparently hadn't got to the point of figuring out that you have to compare country to the specific value. Might be better to restrict the answer to that, rather than providing a ready-made total rewrite which probably doesn't reflect where they're up to skill-wise currently.

Comment: Upvoted since it addresses what I mentioned in my comment and caught the condition around the first `<=18`